# If $U\subset X$ is open, and $\mathscr{F}$ a sheaf on $X$, then $\mathscr{F}_U = (\mathscr{F}_U)_{\bar{U}}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory

I clarify some definitions. If $j:U\to X$ is the inclusion of an open set, and $\mathscr{F}\in\mathfrak{Ab}(X)$, then we define $$\mathscr{F}_U := j_!(\mathscr{F}\vert_U) = j_! j^{-1}\mathscr{F}$$ and if $i:Z\to X$ is the inclusion of $Z = X\setminus U$, then we define $$\mathscr{F}_Z:= i_*(\mathscr{F}\vert_Z) = i_* i^{-1}\mathscr{F}$$ which of course gives us natural maps $\mathscr{F}_U\to\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{F}\to\mathscr{F}_Z$, which form a short exact sequence $$0\to\mathscr{F}_U\to\mathscr{F}\to\mathscr{F}_Z\to 0$$ (by Hartshorne Ex II.2.19). Now, note that by a similar process, we may define a map $$\mathscr{F}_U\to(\mathscr{F}_U)_{\bar{U}}$$ by defining an inclusion map $\imath:\bar{U}\to X$ and using the natural map $$\mathscr{F}_U\to\imath_*\imath^{-1}\mathscr{F}_U$$ which I wish to show is the identity.

I think that it may be enough if I can show that the restriction map $$\varinjlim_{W\supseteq V}\mathscr{F}_U(W)\to\varinjlim_{W\supseteq V\cap U}\mathscr{F}_U(W)$$ is an isomorphism for all opens $V\subseteq\bar{U}$. Now, using the property that $\mathscr{F}_U\vert_x=0$ for all $x\notin U$, I have succeeded in proving injectivity, but I'm struggling with surjectivity.

Comment: Check that the map is an isomorphism on stalks: pulling back to UU, we see it's an iso for stalks in $U$, for $p \not \in U$, the stalk of both sheaves is zero.

Comment: I'm not following something here. As defined, $\mathscr{F}_U$ is a sheaf on $X$ but the notation $\mathscr{F}_U\vert_{\bar{U}}$ would typically mean the restriction of $\mathscr{F}_U$ to $\bar U$ (which is also how the notation seems to be used in the last line). So these aren't sheaves on the same space.

Comment: I replaced it with better notation.